# sorting speeds in c and Julia

Tags: c, performance, julia

I'm working on developing sorting algorithms and was surprised to find c's qsort taking 1.6x as long Julia's default sorting algorithm. I imagine I'm making some sort of benchmarking mistake. Here are my benchmarking programs and their results:

Julia:

```
# time (julia bench.jl)
using Printf
function main()
    len = 100_000_000
    x = rand(Int64, len)
    t = @elapsed sort!(x)
    @printf "%d elements:\nclaim\t%fs" len t
end
main()
```

c

```c
// time (gcc -O3 bench.c && ./a.out)

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int comp (const void * elem1, const void * elem2)
{
    int f = *((int*)elem1);
    int s = *((int*)elem2);
    if (f > s) return  1;
    if (f < s) return -1;
    return 0;
}
long long utime()
{
    struct timeval now_time;

    gettimeofday(&now_time, NULL);

    return now_time.tv_sec * 1000000LL + now_time.tv_usec;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        long length = 100000000;
        long long *x;
        x = (long long *) malloc(length * sizeof(long long));
        if (x == NULL)
        {
            printf("Malloc failed\n");
            return 1;
        }

        for (long cnt = 0 ; cnt < length ; cnt++)
            x[cnt] = rand();

        long long start = utime();
    qsort (x, length, sizeof(*x), comp);
        long long end = utime();

        //for (long cnt = 0 ; cnt < length ; cnt += length/10)
        //      printf("%lld\n", x[cnt]);

        free(x);

        printf ("%ld elements:\nclaim\t%fs", length, (end-start)/1000000.0);

    return 0;
}
```

Results

```
bash-3.2$ time (julia bench.jl)
100000000 elements:
claim   12.405531s
real    0m16.560s
user    0m13.883s
sys 0m1.297s
bash-3.2$ time (gcc -O3 bench.c && ./a.out)
100000000 elements:
claim   20.592641s
real    0m24.604s
user    0m21.352s
sys 0m2.479s
```

Is it true that Julia's algorithm (median of 3 quicksort with an insertion sort base case for less than 20 elements) is substantially faster than c's qsort? Can I sort faster than qsort in c?

Comment: I'm surprised, although, there is no one implementation in C (every C library will have its own).  And in fact there is no guarantee or requirement that `qsort()` will use QuickSort.

Comment: When you use `qsort` in C, there's an inevitable overhead of lots of function calls back to your comparator.  Perhaps the Julia implementation doesn't have that bottleneck.

Comment: You don't usually include compilation time in benchmarks

Comment: I realize Julia is JIT-based, and perhaps that is why you're including the C compilation+linking as part of your bench. But do yourself a favor if you want to know the actual run-time of your C code and measure it post-compile+link. I.e. `time ./a.out`. Also understand you're comparing a lot of different things here, not just sorting. Ex: you're comparing the performance of each implementations rand as well. If you're interested in comparing sorts you need a common source data, and even the acquisition (disk file, etc.) will come into play. In short, benching seems simple; it isn't.

Comment: The OP's "claim" time appears to be sorting-only, exclusive of compilation or random array generation, and is 1.66x faster Julia vs. gcc.

Comment: In practice, I think, "median of 3 quicksort with an insertion sort base case for less than 20 elements," is what is used for most modern implementations of `qsort` as well; _cf_ influential paper, [Bentley, McIlroy 1993, Engineering](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.14.8162&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy to sort faster than C's `qsort`. You could, for example, use C++'s `std::sort`. The C++ library is not faster because it uses a better algorithm; rather, it's because C++'s generics allow the compiler to avoid the overhead of calling the comparison function and a smaller overhead in qsort's swap, which needs to handle elements of arbitrary size.

In the following, the only difference between sortbench-c and sortbench-cc is the use of `std::sort` in the latter:

```
$ diff sortbench-c.c sortbench-cc.cc
1c1
< // time (gcc -O3 sortbench-c.c && ./a.out)
---
> // time (gcc -O3 sortbench-cc.cc && ./a.out)
2a3
> #include <algorithm>
7,14d7
< int comp (const void * elem1, const void * elem2)
< {
<     int f = *((int*)elem1);
<     int s = *((int*)elem2);
<     if (f > s) return  1;
<     if (f < s) return -1;
<     return 0;
< }
38c31
<     qsort (x, length, sizeof(*x), comp);
---
>         std::sort(x, x+length);
```

The difference is dramatic:

```
$ time (gcc -O3 sortbench-c.c && ./a.out)
100000000 elements:
claim   16.673827s
real    0m17.774s
user    0m17.387s
sys     0m0.379s
$ time (gcc -O3 sortbench-cc.cc && ./a.out)
100000000 elements:
claim   9.948971s
real    0m11.133s
user    0m10.926s
sys     0m0.204s
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no performance guarantee for [qsort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort):

> Despite the name, neither C nor POSIX standards require this function to be implemented using quicksort or make any complexity or stability guarantees.

To do a proper sorting benchmark between Julia and C, you will need another implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `rand` functions are [probably] different.

Quicksort is data/order dependent. For example, mergesort will always execute in the same amount of time, regardless of what data it is sorting.

However, quicksort's time will vary depending upon the data.

To do a proper benchmark, do *not* use `rand` unless you write them yourself or *guarantee* that Julia's version and libc's version are *exactly* the same.

I'd write an initialization function for both langs. For example, the requisite `for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) array[i] = length - i;` or some such, so that the initial data is guaranteed to be the same.

You *can* use a random function *if* you have one program generate the array and save it to a file. The other program can then read in the [same] data.

Sometimes, I write a separate program that generates the input data, and saves it to a file. Then, I pass that file off to both programs. This decouples the test data generation from the programs under test.

Comment: I'm thinking the law of large numbers should apply well before 100 000 000, unless there is a different distribution of numbers in the two cases.